# React - Nodejs net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED on SSL Website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ssl, backend

in the last few weeks I coded a little React App with a node js backend (and a Maria DB). It works fine and I was happy that everything worked. Now I discovered a big problem. When using the computers in my university or at work, my axios requests don't work anymore. These computers are using a proxy.

The error message looks like this:

[error message in console while using a vpn/proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqSiT.png)

To reproduce this error you can go on [weihnachten.ruffyg.de/shop](https://weihnachten.ruffyg.de/shop) and use the uVPN Google Addon.

My backend looks like this:

```html
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { exit } = require('process');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');
var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
const host = 'localhost';
const user = 'admin';
const password = 'censored';
const database = 'christmastrees';
const Importer = require('mysql-import');
const importer = new Importer({host, user, password, database});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "admin",
    password: "censored",
    database: "christmastrees",
    port: '3306'
});

app.use(cors({
    prefix: 'weihnachten'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.type('text/plain')
    res.send('Express ist online')
})

app.get('/trees', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM bäume", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result)
    });
})

app.get('/warenkorb', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM warenkorb", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result)
    });
})

app.get('/sum', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT preis FROM `warenkorb`;", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result)
        res.send(result)
    });
})

app.get('/reset', (req, res) => {
    importer.onProgress(progress=>{
        var percent = Math.floor(progress.bytes_processed / progress.total_bytes * 10000) / 100;
        console.log(`${percent}% Completed`);
    });
    importer.import('backup/backup-file.sql').then(()=>{
        var files_imported = importer.getImported();
        console.log(`${files_imported.length} SQL file(s) imported.`);
      }).catch(err=>{
        console.error(err);
      });    
})

app.get('/getanzahl', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT anzahl FROM `warenkorb`;", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result)
    });
})

app.get('/kaufen', (req, res) => {
    con.query("DELETE FROM warenkorb;", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.sendStatus(200)
    });
})

app.post('/deleteandaddback', (req, res) => {
    con.query("DELETE FROM warenkorb WHERE baumart=" + "'" + req.body.baumart + "'" + " AND größe=" + "'" + req.body.größe + "'" + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    con.query("UPDATE `bäume` SET `bestand`=`bestand`+1 WHERE baumart=" + "'" + req.body.baumart + "'" + " AND größenbereich=" + "'" + req.body.größe + "'" + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.sendStatus(200)
    });
})

app.post('/fetchdata', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT bestand,preis FROM `bäume` WHERE baumart=" + "'" + req.body.baumart + "'" + " AND größenbereich=" + "'" + req.body.größe + "'" + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result)
    });
})

app.post('/addtowarenkorb', (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.bestand > 0) {
        result = con.query("SELECT * FROM `warenkorb` WHERE baumart=" + "'" + req.body.baumart + "'" + " AND größe=" + "'" + req.body.größe + "'" + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (result.length > 0) {
                con.query("UPDATE `warenkorb` SET `anzahl`=`anzahl`+1 WHERE `baumart`=" + "'" + req.body.baumart + "'" + " AND `größe`=" + "'" + req.body.größe + "'" + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;    
                });
                con.query("UPDATE `bäume` SET `bestand`=`bestand`-1 WHERE baumart=" + "'" + req.body.baumart + "'" + " AND größenbereich=" + "'" + req.body.größe + "'" + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.send("wurde hinzugefüg & gelöscht")
                });
                
            } else {
                con.query("INSERT INTO `warenkorb` (`baumart`,`größe`,`preis`,`anzahl`) VALUES (" + "'" + req.body.baumart + "'" + "," + "'" + req.body.größe + "'" + "," + "'" + req.body.preis + "'" + ",'1');", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
                con.query("UPDATE `bäume` SET `bestand`=`bestand`-1 WHERE baumart=" + "'" + req.body.baumart + "'" + " AND größenbereich=" + "'" + req.body.größe + "'" + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.send("wurde hinzugefüg & gelöscht")
                });
                
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.send("Bestand ist leer")
    }   
})

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.type('text/plain')
    res.status(404)
    res.send('404 Not found ☕_☕')
})

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server startet on port: ' + port);
});
```

Like you can see my backend is running on Port 3000. I'm still a beginner so please don't laugh at my code haha. Asked a few developer friends but they also didn't know what is wrong. I read alot about a "reverse proxy" I could install on my server, but this seems like a real overkill for me, who has one App on his whole server and like I said, I'm a beginner.

Comment: `To reproduce this error you can go on weihnachten.ruffyg.de/shop` nope, it's cert has been revoked.

Comment: **DEV:** 1. in your React's package.json, add `"proxy": "localhost:3000"` 2. in your React app, remove the host from your fetch commands, i.e. make requests like `fetch('/warenkorb')` ---- **DEPLOY:** 1. set up static file serving in express 2. build the react app and copy the contents of the build folder into express's public folder 3. change the express port to 443 4. deploy the express app (this also requires your DB to be migrated to your host)

Comment: @LucaKiebel Hm cert was revoked a few days ago and I renewed it, should work right now

Comment: @ChrisG wow thanks for your help! Just tryed your way for Development and it works fine! Next step: Deploy :)

Comment: @ChrisG everything worked, but when I try to delete a row from https://weihnachten.ruffyg.de/warenkorb my server deletes the row and reloads the page. but instead of reloading it tries to send a get Request to https://weihnachten.ruffyg.de/warenkorb

Comment: If your React app also uses the /warenkorb route to render a page you're going to run into trouble. And a React app shouldn't have to reload the page either. First, put `/api/` or something at the start of all backend routes (and in your fetch() urls, too), so your server can clearly distinguish between a) a "frontend route" that delivers a page of the app and b) a backend route that is used to get or post data only. This means that express should handle `/api/*` first (data), then `*` next (send back index.html). Are you using react-router?

Comment: (note that in order to add /api to your data-handling routes, you just need to to move them to a new file exactly as they are, then require it and set it up as `app.use('/api', dbRoutes);`)

Comment: @ChrisG ah I see what you mean. Already fixed the problem without seperating front and backend. 

app.get('/warenkorb', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../weihnachten/public', 'index.html'));
})

with the help of this :) but you are right, I should seperate them with /api/ or something else